# How to use boostrap datepicker in webcomponent

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-component, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to use bootstrap datepicker in javascript webcomponent. But seems it's rendering after all of my custom components

I've imported the bootstrap js file like as shown below

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js';
```

And I'm calling the date picker method inside my component's connected callback method

```
connectedCallback() {
       const element = this.shadowEl.querySelector('#' + elementSelectorId);
       jQuery(element).datepicker();
    }
```

And final result is like this

[image]

Comment: did u import the css file as well ?

Comment: I've imoprted like this import '../node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css';
But it's a throwing error. Could you please tell me how to import CSS file in custom component class